# Testing email system in SharePoint 2013 environment

Tags: email, sharepoint-2013, outlook-2013

I've been trying to set up a working mail server in my dev environment, but without success.
I need to test the incoming mails to a ImageLibrary. Need a easy way to set this up, and I cant use exchange. Trying to get hmailserver to work, but no luck. Anyone done a config for outlook13/sharepoint13 with hmailserver for incoming mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to try [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/), it is a great tool for testing email capabilities in SharePoint.

> [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) - Windows 7/Vista/XP/2003/2010 compatible dummy SMTP
>   server. Sits in the system tray and does not deliver the received
>   messages. The received messages can be quickly viewed, saved and the
>   source/structure inspected. Useful for testing/debugging software that
>   generates email

[image]

[image]